# how to debug symfony error "Untrusted Host" in production

Tags: symfony, amazon-web-services, monolog

## problem :

Running symfony 3.4, I just preemptively took a look at symfony's logs and seen some strange errors :

> request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\BadRequestHttpException: "Untrusted Host "52.47.154.91"

It's strange because I it is not the IP of my server...

## question :

How would you investigate this?

=> I think that I need more details in the log, but I don't know how to make monolog be more verbose on this error only

---

complementary information :
I'm hosted on AWS I know thaht need some special tuning, but I think that my app.php is well configured for running behind an ELB:

```
Request::setTrustedProxies(
// trust *all* requests
    array('127.0.0.1', $request->server->get('REMOTE_ADDR')),
    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_AWS_ELB
);
```

and The IP that is loggued is the IP of the ELB (load balancer)

Comment: What I think is that is is the sign of a IP scan that find my load balancer IP, and that log is totally normal since symfony act as it should : it refuse to serve the content.

Comment: According to the documentation, this can be manage in the Amazon configuration, have you explored this possibility? (documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment/proxies.html#but-what-if-the-ip-of-my-reverse-proxy-changes-constantly)

Comment: only the load balancer can access the web server, but it is quite the case.
It trigger a log only because the host is forbidden (it is again normal since the only autorized host it the official domain name, not the ip of the load balancer.
By investingating the problem, I becomed quite confident of this.
My question is more about how to leverage more logs and make myself 100% sure of this.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have something like this in the config

    `trusted_hosts:
        - "%domain%"`

either remove it or add the IP

Comment: I do not want to authorize this IP to serve the content of the website.
So the error is right. I should want to have more info around this error to better analyze what caused it. But I'm pretty confident that it is due to robot's IP scan.